# Why my table does not have four-sided edges?

Tags: tables

I need my table to have all edges.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|p{90mm}}
      \hline
      number & result \\
      \hline
      \hline
      0 & only \\
      \hline
      \hline
      1 & wrong
      \\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `|` indicates where vertical lines should be placed, so if you not only want a line between your two columns, but also in front and afterwards, use `{|l|p{90mm}|}` instead of `{l|p{90mm}}`

---

My personal opinion: please don't put your data away behind bars. Have a look at http://betterposters.blogspot.de/2012/08/the-data-prison.html or https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf